# Java: Count occurrence of letters in a String

Tags: java

I am trying to write a program that counts the occurrence of letters in a string. For example, if the user inputs "Java", it will display "j: 1 a: 2 v:1". However, there seems to be something wrong with my program, and when I input the word java this is what it shows "j: 0 a: 1 v: 0"

```
    Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String s = myScanner.nextLine();
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int cnt = 0;
    int length = s.length();
    char ch;
    for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        ch = s.charAt(i);
        if (s.indexOf(ch) < i)
            continue;
        for (j = (i + 1); j < length; j++) {
            if (s.charAt(j) == ch)
                cnt++;
        }
        System.out.println(ch + ": " + cnt);
        cnt = 0;
    }
```

Comment: Caps are considered to be shouting on the web. Please use normal casing.

Comment: Start by writing a pure function that counts the occurrences of letters in a string. (The method signature will look something like `static Map<Char, Integer> countLetters(String s)`.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your desired output:

```
Enter your String: Mascarena
M: 1
a: 3
s: 1
c: 1
r: 1
e: 1
n: 1
```

Error in your code:

```
for (j = (i + 1); j < length; j++) { //It is omitting the first letter and searches the remaining
    if (s.charAt(j) == ch)
        cnt++;
}
```

Rectified:

```
for (j = 0; j < length; j++) { //For a specific letter searches the whole string.
    if (s.charAt(j) == ch)
        cnt++;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your 2nd for-loop is not searching the entire word for each letter.

For example, when searching for `j` it is only looking at `ava` because it starts at `i + 1` which is

```
(0 + 1) = 1
```

this `a` in the string `java` as `j` would be index at `0`. Change

```
for (j = (i + 1)..)
```

to

```
(j = 0..)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public static String numberOfOccurence(String data) {
    String result = "";

    while (!data.isEmpty()) {
        result += String.valueOf(data.charAt(0))+ StringUtils.countOccurrencesOf(data, String.valueOf(data.charAt(0)));
        data = data.replaceAll(String.valueOf(data.charAt(0)), "");
    }

    return result;
}
```

input: aabacbd

output: a3b2c1d1